# updating an Input field affects others, v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a cart with an input field bound via v-model. when I increase the quantity of one product,the quantity of all the products is also updated, How do I prevent this from happening such that I update only the quantity of one product?
my Html

```
<div v-for="(product, index) in cartProducts" :key="index">
          <li>{{product.description}}</li>
          <input type="number"  v-model="quantity">
          <img src="imageurl" height="150">
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm " disabled>{{product.price }}</button>

        </div>
```

vue data Property

```
data () {
    return {
      quantity: 1
    }
```

Comment: Don't bind the count to the same variable. Can't really help more without any code.

Comment: @FINDarkside I have added my code sample, I hope it's clear

Comment: `cartProducts` should not be an array of products, but rather an array of `{ product, quantity }`

Answer (score 2):

You need separate quantity for each product, so add quantity field to the product and then bind to it:

```
<input type="number"  v-model="product.quantity">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use .map to assign quantity to each product :

```
this.cartProducts.map(function(elem){
   elem.quantity = 1;
   return elem;
});
```

in your html :

```
<input type="number"  v-model="product.quantity">
```

example : https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/3945/

Comment: quality over quantity, nice 